# How to create a 24 bits bitmap overlapping two images, one with alpha channel

Tags: bitmap

I would like to "sum" 2 bitmaps, the first is a 24 bits and the second is a 32 bits, so with alpha channel. I would like to obtain a third 24 bits bitmap representing the "shade" effect.
In other words, assuming both bitmaps have the same size, for each pixel: [Bitmap 1 RGB] + [Bitmap 2 RGBA] = [Bitmap 3 RGB]

---

SOLUTION FOUND

For each channel, the formula is: *result = ((alpha * fg) + ((255 - alpha) * bg)) / 255;